# Unable to connect to spark-sql cli

Tags: apache-spark, command-line-interface, apache-spark-sql

I am using CDH 5.5.7 quick start VM which has Spark 1.6.0 running. I am trying to connect to the spark-sql cli but it fails.
According to this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-spark-sql-cli) by issuing `spark-sql` command I should be able to enter the cli but I get the below error.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-sql
-bash: spark-sql: command not found
```

I have also tried the below and getting the same error

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ./bin/spark-sql
-bash: ./bin/spark-sql: No such file or directory
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This probably will not work in Cloudera's distribution of Spark.

I think they stopped shipping `spark-sql` since CDH 5.4.

`spark-sql` is not included because CDH Spark doesn't have Thift service or because of some other reason.

I can't find confirmation in online documentation, but my CDH 5.8 doesn't have `spark-sql` in neither Spark 1.6 nor Spark 2.0 parcels.